# execute sampler every 10 minutes in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have sampler which generates token, this token need to be passed to APIs as header. I want to execute token generator sampler every 10 minutes as the token will expire after 10 minutes. How can I handle this in JMeter?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be creating a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 virtual user and 1 HTTP Request sampler which will be refreshing the token.

In order to make it happen each 10 minutes add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and configure it to introduce delay of 600000 milliseconds

To pass the token to other Thread Group(s) you can convert the JMeter Variable into a JMeter Property via [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function and read it back using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P). If you need a token per thread (virtual user) consider using [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) (in this case the number of threads must be equal to the total number of virtual users)

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)